# Free causes a error : free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001d04018

Tags: c, pointers

I tried to compile the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int *p = (int*) malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    p++;
    p++;
    free(p);
}
```

But it gives me the following error.

*** Error in `/home/a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001d04018 ***
Aborted.

I think I am still within the allocated limits of size 4 ints. But then why invalid pointer. Can some one help.

Comment: You call `free()` only on pointer returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 4):

You are invoking undefined behavior.

From [free manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free):

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, **which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc()**. Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs.

It doesn't matter whether you are inside allocated region or not. The pointer must be the same that was allocated before.

The rationale for being it undefined is that typical implementation (this is implementation defined) must remember other metadata related to the allocation, e.g. the allocation size, in some data structure in order to free them later. If `ptr` is not same as returned by allocation function then there is no way to lookup into this data structure to get those metadata during freeing.

Answer (score 2):

The `free()` function can only operate on a pointer that has been directly allocated with `malloc()` or any of its companions.

If you change the pointer you'll have errors like this, that modified pointer was never allocated.

"Close enough" does not count. It must be identical to the pointer you got in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The contract for `malloc` and `free` is fairly simple. The pointer value (the address) you pass to `free` must be **exactly** a pointer value you got from `malloc`.

*Exactly*, and not in the same block, however close. It must match exactly. You modify the pointer before passing it back (you increment), so you violate that contract. This is going to cause undefined behavior. And you experience it in the from of a crash. It could be worse, it could appear to work. Until it blows up in your face later for no apparent reasons. That's the nature of undefined behavior. Avoid it.